# .change() .css width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wanna change the width of a css when the value of a text to change on value.

**Javascript**:

```
<script>
 $("inpu").change( function() {
 $(#calidad).css({
  width: function(index, value) {
    return parseFloat(value) * 1.2;
  }, 
  });
  });
</script>
```

**CSS** :

```
#calidad{ width: 20px; height: 15px; background-color: #f33; }
```

**html**:

```
<input type="text" id="inpu" name="inpu" value="2">
<div id="calidad"></div>
```

Comment: You don't just randomly throw CSS in.. and both of your jQuery selector are screwed up. `"inpu"` should be `"input"` and `#calidad` should be `"#calidad"`.

Comment: do you want to change the width to the value entered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed your code and made a jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/xWXWD/

Both selectors were incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I may not understand the question, but do you want to change the width to the val of the input?

here is an example using px (you could use em, points, etc)

```
$(function() {   
 $("#inpu").change( function() {
        $('#calidad').css({
              width: getWidth});    
        });
});

    function getWidth() {
     return $('#inpu').val()  + 'px' 
    }
```

here is a live example using a forked version of Steve's fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pK2qR/